# Implementing wildcard file copy/rename (test.txt + *.js = test.js)

Tags: javascript, batch-file, wildcard

I wrote a file manager, and I receive a number of requests to implement a wildcard(asterisk copy/rename, file mask copy/rename) based file copy/rename. I found myself confused, because I actually have no idea what kind of algorithm is behind this functionality. I only know that I was always renaming like this `fileList=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']`, `wildcard='*.js'` and `fileList` would become `['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js']`
`file='noname.txt'`, `wildcard mask='note1.txt'`, the result file is note1.txt.

But I noticed that things like "abc*.xy" are also possible. It just confuses me, how to implement such a functionality? I cannot find any wiki or docs that would explain in detail how this worked in Windows/DOS. How complex is the algorithm behind this? Should I look for dots and start from there, or there is sort of regular expression search or whatever?

In BASH this does not work, I tried `mv test.txt *.js` and I got a file named `*.js`, but in Windows I suppose `ren test.txt *.js` would work as expected.

In the end I need a function declared similarly to this:

```
function getCopyRenameFileName(src, mask) // returns new name
```

Comment: The "how windows rename command wildcards works" can be found [here](http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

Comment: wow, how did you find it?!